# Why does windows.dispatchEvent() does not work on app.component.ts on Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

At my app.component.ts in my ngOnInit I used this method called log to send a dispatch event. This will be listened inside a preload script when I load my angular application into an Electron webview tag. For some reason every other part of my angular frontend this dispatch works but when I try to do this in the app.component.ts it never works.

```
public log(level: LogLevel, message: string) {
        const data = {
            message: '============== frontend : ' + message,
            level
        };
        window.dispatchEvent(new MessageEvent('logMessage', {
            data,
            bubbles: false,
            cancelable: false
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this part of the code I don't see why it wouldn't work. It's important to check the other side, where you're listening to this `logMessage` event. Firing ngOnInit events from angular primary component might cause concurrency problems, you need to make sure your listener registration is done *before* this event is fired.